# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException when trying to make POST call ( https://url/test)

Tags: java, spring

```
## sendPost method to make the POST call. It is fetching the url and also printing the data properly in the below method. ##

     Public static void sendPost(String url, String data) throws Exception {
                    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            // add header
            post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(data);

            post.setEntity(requestEntity);
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.[`enter link description here`][1]append(line);
            }

            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
    }   


@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String sendTestData(@RequestBody TestDTO TestData) {
        try{
            log.info("Data got to ingestion rest: "+TestData);
            String jsonData = new Gson().toJson(TestData).toString();
            System.out.println("jsonData=="+ jsonData);
            boolean result = dataIngestionHandler.insertData(jsonData);
            if(result){
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error while inserting data into the db!!");
            return "FAIL" + ex.getMessage();
        }
        return "FAIL";
    }
```

I am sending the data from the `sendPost` method to the controller method, but in response it is giving:

> 405 exception
>
> Exact error
>   code:{"timestamp":1467696109585,"status":405,"error":"Method Not
>   Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request
>   method 'POST' not supported","path":"/test"}.

The entire setup is running fine and data is getting inserted into the db when I run it on localhost. But as soon as I push it to cloud, the following exception comes up

Comment: Just an idea: could this be a CORS issue? You might try to allow POST methods explicitly for your servlet. You could override the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and add custom mappings. Look here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

Comment: Try to send the request from any HTTP request tools such as post man. If you don't have any issue with that mostly it could be via CORS.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have tried with postman but still it is giving the same error.On localhost it works fine.the localhost link is http kind and when i push it to cloud the link is https kind so is this creating the issue?